# Electrolysis in OpenModelica

Tags: fluid, modelica, openmodelica

I am very new to OpenModelica.

I have a few queries to solve my modelling of the electrolysis cell. I have a package of Electrolysis cell, then a media file and a model file. The media file contains the mass fraction of the cathode lets say (90% H2O and 10% H2) and the anode with (40% O2 and 60% N2).

My questions are:

1. Where can I define the other parameters such as temp, pressure and mass flow for the cathode and anode?
2. How can I give these values to the port anode and cathode? Also, use these values in the model to do further calculations.
3. After the calculation, how can I assign the calculated values (mass fraction, temp, pressure and mass flow) to outlet ports of the anode and cathode?
4. If there is a power input how can I provide it through a port? also how to access that value in the model.

Till now I have my model file with the equation, input (given as constant) and calculated output. So my major question is how can I assign these inputs to inlet ports (cathode and anode) and also how to assign the calculated values to the outlet port (cathode and anode).

Comment: Not sure if this is useful, but I have read a paper where they model an Electrolyzer using openmodelica, and they share their code.  Look at page 7 (electrolyzer code) and 15 (full source code). If you cannot access the paper, let me know I can send it to you. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/304745172_Efficient_simulation_of_Hybrid_Renewable_Energy_Systems https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0360319916318316 https://www.fceia.unr.edu.ar/%7Ekofman/files/hres.mo